# Mockito - creating a mock as Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a simple use case wherein I need to create a mock object through spring. (I know there are better alternatives like `@Mock`).

The Class which I need to mock say `ClassToMock` is like this:

```
public classToMock {
  public ClassToMock (String a, String b, int c)
  ...
  }
  //other methods omitted
}
```

In my Spring Bean I have:

```
<bean id="xyz" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
  <constructor-arg value="some val"/>
  <constructor-arg value="some other val"/>
  <constructor-arg type="int" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting:

> No matching factory method founnd: factory method 'mock(String, String, int)'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mix some concerns.

`factory-method` attribute refers to a static method which returns the instance you want to create.

Besides, either you instantiate a `org.mockito.Mockito` instance, either you instantiate a `ClassToMock` instance. You cannot use parameters constructor of one (`ClassToMock`class) to use them with the constructor or the other one (`Mockito` class).

Besides, Mockito, alone cannot mock constructor. And why do you would need to mock the constructor ?

If you want to create a instance of your class with some predefined value for your test, you can declare it in your xml spring conf :

```
<bean id="xyz" class="ClassToMock" >
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="some val"/>
  <constructor-arg index="1" value="some other val"/>
  <constructor-arg index="2" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You are correct. I have to pass in the fully qualified class name which I need to mock as the constructor arg.